# MySQL: filter child records, include all siblings

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering, inner-join, query-optimization

There are two MySQL tables:

```
tparent(id int, some data...)
tchild(id int, parent_id int, some data...)
```

I need to return all columns (parent plus **all children**) where at least one of the children matches some criteria.

My current solution:

```
-- prepare sample data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tparent;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tchild;

CREATE TABLE tparent (id int, c1 varchar(10), c2 date, c3 float);
CREATE TABLE tchild(id int, parent_id int, c4 float, c5 varchar(20), c6 date);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tparent_id_IDX USING BTREE ON tparent (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tchild_id_IDX USING BTREE ON tchild (id);

INSERT INTO tparent 
VALUES
  (1, 'a', '2021-01-01', 1.23)
, (2, 'b', '2021-02-01', 1.32)
, (3, 'c', '2021-01-03', 2.31);

INSERT INTO tchild
VALUES
  (10, 1, 22.333, 'argh1', '2000-01-01')
, (20, 1, 33.222, 'argh2', '2000-01-02')
, (30, 1, 44.555, 'argh3', '2000-02-02')
, (40, 2, 33.222, 'argh4', '2000-03-02')
, (50, 3, 33.222, 'argh5', '2000-04-02')
, (60, 3, 33.222, 'argh6', '2000-05-02');


-- the query
WITH parent_filter AS
(
SELECT
    parent_id
FROM
    tchild
WHERE
    c4>44
)
SELECT
    p.*,
    c.*
FROM
    tparent p
JOIN tchild c ON p.id = c.parent_id
JOIN parent_filter pf ON p.id = pf.parent_id;
```

It returns 3 rows for parent id 1 and child ids 10, 20, 30, because child id 30 has a matching record. It does not return data for any other parent id.

However, I am querying `tchild` twice here (first in the CTE, then again in the main query). As both tables are relatively big (10s - 100s millions of rows, 2-5 child records per parent record on average), I am hitting performance / timing issues.

Is there a better way of achieving this filtering? I.e. without having to query `tchild` table more than once?

Comment: please provide a [mre] and read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: fair point, question now updated with reproducible example

Comment: it doesn't return any other parent, because 30 is the only one with c4 > 40

Comment: Exactly, this is what I need. I need to include **all** parent records where **at least one** child record matches criteria.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this version?

```
SELECT *
FROM tparent p
JOIN tchild c ON p.id = c.parent_id AND <criteria>
```

this way you limit the tchild table with the createria before the actual join

Comment: This will filter out other child records of a parent. I need to include all child records of a parent, not just the matching ones.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can use this instead:

```sql
select p.*, c.*
from tparent p
join tchild c 
on p.id = c.parent_id 
where exists (select 1 from tchild where <crtiteria>)
```

This should retrieve all rows for parent and child join when there is at least one record in the child table meeting the criteria.